# Windows 7 Installation Fails at 7% Extraction on Dell

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installation, dell-xps

Alright, before I begin I want to clarify some points so no one wastes their time giving solutions that have already been addressed and haven't worked:

1. I am aware that this is a common error (0x80070570) on Dell
   machines.
2. I have changed the settings in the BIOS as suggested by both
   Microsoft and Dell forums i.e. changed the drive settings from AHCI
   to ATA.
3. The BIOS version shows as A12.
4. The processor is 32 Bit.
5. It is a clean install on a Dell XPS M1330 machine. There is no other
   Operating System on it.
6. The ISO file used is the same one used to install the operating
   system I'm on right now and it was downloaded from the official
   Microsoft website. It runs on every other computer BUT the Dell.
7. I'm trying to install Windows Ultimate 32 bit.
8. I have checked the Ram and there is no problem whatsoever with the
   hardware.
9. The computer was already running a Windows 7 Ultimate on it when I
   bought it but I had to uninstall it because it was a pirated version
   and I wanted to install the genuine one on it.
10. I have tried to only install Windows through my USB since I don't
     have a working DVD-Drive on me right now (that's another problem
     but will worry about it on another thread).

So...

1. I'm lost right now. Every time I start it stops at 7%. I'm guessing
   the following might be wrong:
2. The data transfer between the USB and the HDD isn't doing alright,
   and it stops at 7%. But if that's the case, then how can it boot
   from the USB and also copy upto 7% in the first place?
3. If the USB is the problem, and seeing that I do not have a working
   DVD drive, can I install Windows by copying setup files from the USB
   to the HDD? If so, how do I go about doing that? I can get to the
   command prompt when I boot from my USB. What do I do after that?
4. Would changing the install from Ultimate to Professional or Home or
   something help? I only have the key to Ultimate, but I can install
   it without the key for a little while if that would fix the problem.

Any other suggestions?

I do not have any technical background. Whatever I've tried, I've done it after reading it online, so I would really appreciate a detailed explanation. I've read other entries on here as well, but they haven't helped solve my problem.

Comment: "I have checked the Ram and there is no problem whatsoever with the hardware"  There's more hardware than RAM in the world. ;) Did you try different media (depending on how you're installing: different disk, different optical drive, and/or different USB stick)?  How about drive checks?  How long did you test the memory for (anything less than several hours to multiple days is NOT a good RAM check).

Comment: also, have you seen this: http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=177488

Comment: @techie007 Yes I'm aware there is more hardware than just RAM. Anyway, yes I've tried it with multiple different USBs that work fine. The USB installed Windows fine on my computer where I'm writing this. I left the memory check running all night long. And yes, I've tried the simple solution that link provided. Another thing, like I said in the post, I don't have a working CD/DVD drive. I could try copying installation files from my USB to the HDD, but I don't know how to go about it after I get to the command prompt from the system recovery area.

Comment: How are you installing from USB?  With the Microsoft [USB/DVD iso tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)?  Is the 7% stalling happening at the initial "loading files" phase, or are you able to go through the config and then it's failing on the "full" install?  If you can config, have you tried deleting the partition and reformatting?  Would you consider putting something like Ubuntu on it temporarily as a test that nothing else is wrong with the system? (It's a pretty quick install.)

Comment: @techturtle Yes I used the Microsoft's USB/DVD tool to create the USB. The 7% thing is after I format the HDD, and select it to install the OS. Then it says "That's all we need right now" and the second step there is "Extracting Files" or something, that's where it crashes around 7% and tells me "Windows can't install the file..." with the error code I posted above. It seems like its a recurring problem with DELL m1330 if USB is in use, that's why I'm wondering how I could copy files to the HDD and try from there.

Comment: @techturtle I have Ubuntu on one of my systems and I know that its easy to install but I would want to avoid it, if possible, if there's a way for me to be able to install Windows without having to install another OS on it.

Comment: @nickecarlo I didn't mean dual boot or anything, just get Ubuntu on there and make sure it didn't cause any problems.  If it did, then you may have other hardware issues to work out.  Not sure if you have seen this or if you could configure it to your current situation, but [this site](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7943-install-windows-7-fast-without-dvd-usb-device.html) has a process for installing w/o DVD or USB.  EDIT: [This site](http://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows-7-without-USB-or-DVD-without-upgra/) might actually be more what you're looking for.

Comment: @techturtle Thanks for your help. I am going to see if any of these suggestions work and then report back here. Right now I'm trying to figure out a way to use Windows setup to copy files to a HDD partition and make it bootable. If it doesn't work then I will have to use good ole Ubuntu to get done what Windows couldn't do.

Comment: @nickecarlo The 2nd link I posted (instructables.com) has exactly that: copying windows files to the hard drive, making it bootable, and installing Windows.  It assumes you have a way to connect the hard drive in question to another computer with a DVD drive, but I would think you have the equipment to do that since that's what you are trying to do. :)  Good luck, I look forward to hearing that you got it running!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows-7-without-USB-or-DVD-without-upgra/ has step-by-step instructions on copying Windows setup files to the hard drive, making it bootable, and installing Windows 7.  From the site:

> **How to CLEAN Install Windows 7 directly from Hard drive – NO DVD or USB needed!!**
>
> For example, you have a netbook or desktop that you want to install
>   Windows 7 onto, but can’t use DVD or USB for whatever reason (or don't
>   want to, like me). This method will allow you to boot and install
>   Windows directly from the hard drive. This guide involves plugging the
>   hard drive into another working computer, preparing the hard drive,
>   placing it back in the system, and installing Windows as usual.